# Stop Pulse Secure from opening at startup

Tags: macos, vpn, juniper

I have installed Juniper's Pulse Secure VPN utility and it automatically opens at startup. Unfortunately, the app doesn't behave like any other, i.e., I cannot disable it through:

> System Preferences → Users & Groups → Login Items

I've done some research on the Internet and I found that the file that is responsible for the startup opening is:

> /Library/LaunchAgents/net.pulsesecure.pulsetray.plist

If I delete the file, Pulse Secure doesn't open at startup, but whenever I open it, it won't work as expected (won't connect to any VPN).

Does anyone know how to prevent it from opening at startup AND make it work at the same time?

I attach the content of the file if it's of some aid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.pulsesecure.pulsetray</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>Aqua</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Pulse Secure.app/Contents/Plugins/JamUI/PulseTray.app/Contents/MacOS/PulseTray</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://kb.pulsesecure.net/articles/Pulse_Secure_Article/KB26679

Using Automater, create an app to run the following script during boot:

`launchctl unload –w /Library/LaunchAgents/net.pulsesecure.pulsetray.plist`

This prevents Pulse from launching at boot.

Save this .app file, and add it to your Login Items

Comment: What a joke. The developers should be ashamed. How dare they write software that auto-starts without putting it in Apple start-up preferences!?

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, after the latest Pulse/Ivanti update, I had to change the file name to /Library/LaunchAgents/net.pulsesecure.pulseagent.plist

Answer (score 4):

I copied `PulseTray.app` into Applications so I could run it from Spotlight:

`sudo cp -r /Applications/Pulse\ Secure.app/Contents/Plugins/JamUI/PulseTray.app/ /Applications/`

It appears with a terminal showing output, but I just hide this in the dock and forget about it.

Answer (score 4):

Change the bold `<false/>` to `<true/>`.  I tested it just now on my MacBook macOS Sierra and it stopped the auto launch at bootup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.pulsesecure.pulsetray</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>Aqua</string>
    </array>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/Pulse Secure.app/Contents/Plugins/JamUI/PulseTray.app/Contents/MacOS/PulseTray</string>
    </array>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    **<false/>**
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This prevents Pulse from starting automatically but you'll need to run the full command when you want to use it:

/Applications/Pulse Secure.app/Contents/Plugins/JamUI/PulseTray.app/Contents/MacOS/PulseTray

This works great for me.